# Extremely stressed person

Tags: emotional-responses

I have a classmate who is extremely stressed up. He has a 4.0 GPA and is an exception student. But seems like he is pushing himself way too hard and this is very obvious if you talk to him. He is very frequently showing up awake the entire night.

He doesn't have any heath issue (at least he says so) aside from overworking himself and missing sleep constantly without taking any breaks the entire year.

Will professors give a great recommendation letter to such a student? Won't they be concerned about his ability to handle stress in the long term? Talking to him makes you wonder how long it will take him to collapse.

Comment: It might make you wonder, but a recommendation is not the place for "what ifs" and suspicions, it is the place to state things about a person you actually know.

Comment: Doesn´t really matter if this lifestyle will influence any recommendation letters because it is very probable that this will lead to burnout / mental heatlh problems or even physical health problems sooner or later...

Comment: @JayFromA But will it?

Comment: @NET_GUY Depends on the extend of doing it but like I said, it´s probable. The "missing sleep" part alone can be enough to cause health problems on the long run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think professors will take his personal life into consideration as long as he has great academic performance or social skills if needed for whatever he is trying to get reference letters for.